# Why does creating a flask.Response object seemingly lose my data?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python/Flask application that uses `flask.jsonify()`

Here is the code from my application: I'm creating a `flask.Response` object by using `jsonify()` and I'm printing its values. Note the 3 arguments I'm sending in to `jsonify()`. I will want to get them back out later:

```
x = jsonify(message="Hello World!", status_code=90210, status=404)
print "x = %s\n" % str(x))
print "x.status_code = %s\n" % str(x.status_code))
print "x.status = %s\n" % str(x.status))
print "dir(x) = %s\n" % str(dir(x))
```

What's the output from the above? It is shown below. It makes no sense.

```
x = <Response 82 bytes [200 OK]>
x.status_code = 200
x.status = 200 OK
dir(x) = ['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_ensure_sequence', '_get_mimetype_params', '_on_close', '_status', '_status_code', 'accept_ranges', 'add_etag', 'age', 'allow', 'autocorrect_location_header', 'automatically_set_content_length', 'cache_control', 'calculate_content_length', 'call_on_close', 'charset', 'close', 'content_encoding', 'content_language', 'content_length', 'content_location', 'content_md5', 'content_range', 'content_type', 'data', 'date', 'default_mimetype', 'default_status', 'delete_cookie', 'direct_passthrough', 'expires', 'force_type', 'freeze', 'from_app', 'get_app_iter', 'get_data', 'get_etag', 'get_wsgi_headers', 'get_wsgi_response', 'headers', 'implicit_sequence_conversion', 'is_sequence', 'is_streamed', 'iter_encoded', 'last_modified', 'location', 'make_conditional', 'make_sequence', 'mimetype', 'mimetype_params', 'response', 'retry_after', 'set_cookie', 'set_data', 'set_etag', 'status', 'status_code', 'stream', 'vary', 'www_authenticate']
```

It shows the `status` and `status_code` both to be 200, even though I sent in different values. Why have I lost this data? Where can I find the `"Hello World"` string that I put into it earlier? There is no `.message()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword arguments to `jsonify()` are part of the **JSON payload**, not the response metadata. You created a JSON object with `message`, `status_code` and `status` keys, these are entirely *separate* from the `Response` object attributes:

```
>>> x.get_data()
'{\n  "message": "Hello World!", \n  "status": 404, \n  "status_code": 90210\n}'
>>> x.headers
Headers([('Content-Type', u'application/json'), ('Content-Length', u'74')])
```

The `Response.get_data()` method shows the actual payload of the response.

See the [`jsonify()` documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.jsonify):

> Creates a `Response` with the **JSON representation** of the given arguments with an *application/json* mimetype. The arguments to this function are the same as to the `dict` constructor.

(bold emphasis mine)

Set the status afterwards, or wrap the result in a new `Response` object. The following works:

```
x = jsonify(message="Hello World!", status_code=90210, status=404)
x.status_code = 404
```

See the [Werkzeug `Response` documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse) for what attributes and methods are supported.